# Help require in PHP Time processing

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a php project in which at a point I have a function returning time in 4:35 AM in this format. Now All i want to do is to calculate how much hours left in 12:00 AM. What I need in the end is number of hours remaining like if we substract these two time it should return 7:25 or it would be better if it return number of seconds remaining. Please help !!

Comment: 12:00 AM is midnight. The span from 4:35 AM to the next midnight is 19:25, not 7:25. Do you want the time until next midnight or next noon?

Answer (score 2):

```
$from = '4:35 AM';
$to = '11:00 AM';

echo strtotime($to)-strtotime($from);
```

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate the time left to the next midnight, you can do something like this:

```
$seconds = strtotime('12:00AM +1 day') - strtotime('4:35AM');
```

That will give you the difference in seconds. If you want the difference in hours, you can do it like this:

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime('12:00AM') + $seconds);
```

The output is 19:25.